# The distance formula used in Kernel K-means in tslearn

Tags: machine-learning, python, clustering, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I am reading the [document](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gen_modules/clustering/tslearn.clustering.KernelKMeans.html) of the class tslearn.clustering.KernelKMeans and find its [source code](https://github.com/tslearn-team/tslearn/blob/fa40028/tslearn/clustering/kmeans.py#L136-L457). I have questions on the function _compute_dist from the source code which I quote as follows

```
def _compute_dist(self, K, dist):
        """Compute a n_samples x n_clusters distance matrix using the kernel
        trick."""
        sw = self.sample_weight_

        for j in range(self.n_clusters):
            mask = (self.labels_ == j)

            if numpy.sum(mask) == 0:
                raise EmptyClusterError("try smaller n_cluster or better "
                                        "kernel parameters")

            # NB: we use a normalized kernel so k(x,x) = 1 for all x
            # (including the centroid)
            dist[:, j] = 2 - 2 * numpy.sum(sw[mask] * K[:, mask],
                                           axis=1) / sw[mask].sum()
```

Suppose $\phi$ is the feature mapping for the kernel $K$. Notice that $K(x,y)=\phi(x)^\top\phi(y)$ and we assume the normalized condition: $K(x,x)=1$ for all $x$. Now for a point $y$ and a cluster being composed of points $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$, the distance is computed using kernel trick as

\begin{align*}
\left\|\phi(y)-\underbrace{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\phi(x_i)}_{centroid}\right\|_2^2 &= K(y,y) - \frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n K(y,x_i) + \frac{1}{n^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n K(x_i,x_j)\\
&= 1 - \frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n K(y,x_i) + \frac{1}{n^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n K(x_i,x_j).
\end{align*}

Comparing with the code, it seems that the term
$$\frac{1}{n^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n K(x_i,x_j)$$
should be equal to $1$. But I do not think it holds. Do I miss anything? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In kmeans, for reassignment of a point $\mathbf{y}$ to a cluster,
you need to compute
$d(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{c}_n)$ for the $n$th cluster.
For (squared) Euclidean distance, this writes
$$
d(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{c}_n) =
\| \mathbf{y} \|^2 
+ \| \mathbf{c}_n \|^2 
- 2 \mathbf{y}^T \mathbf{c}_n
$$
In kernel, you compute
$$
d(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{c}_n) =
k(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{y})
+ k(\mathbf{c}_n,\mathbf{c}_n)
- 2 k(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{c}_n)
=
2 
- 2 k(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{c}_n)
=
2- 2 
\frac1N \sum_n k(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x}_n)
$$
since you are using 'normalized' kernel'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am questionable about what $\mathbf{c}_n$ refers in your answer. I assume that you mean $\mathbf{c}_n$ is $\frac{1}{n}\sum_n\mathbf{x}_n$ then I donot think the last equation $k(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{c}_n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_n k(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x}_n)$ is correct, for example $k$ is the Gaussian kernel.

Comment: I think my answer is indeed wrong and that yours is more correct. Maybe the Python code was built on the same reasoning error...